# Apigee entity primary key

Tags: apigee, apigee-baas

I have a custom entity `Entity1`, and I need to make it `id` field primary key. How to do it?
I expect that when I call `mDataClient.createEntityAsync` - it will update the entity if the same `id` already exists, currently it creates a new one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now we do not support a primary key other than 'name' which is the default on all collections.  Can you use 'name' instead of 'id'?